# How to alter a table using mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, insert-update, alter-table

I need to add a new field for 'status' on MongoDB collection. I got so many tutorials but it never point-out the type of field. I need an varchar(5)

Is the below snippet is right for my requirement.

```
db.users.update(
    { },
    { $set: { Status: []} },
    { multi: true }
)
```

Comment: Since the answers so far don't make this sufficiently clear IMHO: **MongoDB collections do not have fields**, individual *documents* have fields. 'Collection' is not just another word for 'table' - it's a completely different approach. There are no 'columns'. The documents in a single collection don't have to have the same structure, they could look entirely different. If you're worried about evolving schemas, you can add new fields lazily where required, but make sure your code can cope with missing fields.

Comment: Listen to the wisdom being spread here. And mostly by those with greater knowledge than those who attempted to answer. MongoDB == "Schemaless" == "Not all records are the same". You can pull some things in application logic but you also need to consider why are you using MongoDB in the first place? Because all the other kids said it was cool? Bad idea. Use a NoSQL solution because it is what "fits" your solution. No other reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB does not use tables. Use Collections, maybe you must study deeper this concepts because you must change the classic E/R mind to the new concept (Collections).

I recommend you to use mongoose and define your models with JSON. There are tons of tutorials and documentation about this.

EDIT:

As I mentioned before try to use this if you are using a high level language. http://mongoosejs.com/ It's very simple and works perfectly.

If you are using commands directly in your mongo shell read this link.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongo-shell/

You will get essentials concepts as collections, how can be this collections transformed in a dynamic, lazy way.

Comment: Okay so how to alter the collection for adding new field. Is there any way to accomplish. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Your command will add the field `Status` as an empty array to all document in the collection `users`. In mongodb there is no varchar (only string) and you cannot restrict it contain only 5 characters. The restriction needs to be done by some kind of application logic.

The supported types of mongodb can be found [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/).

Answer (score 0):

My requirement is to add user in colletion :

My initial collection was :

[image]

and to add user in my existing collection.

```
            let response = await resumeTemplates.updateOne(
            { templateID: templateID },
            {
                $set: { 'templateImg': templateImg, user: user },
                $currentDate: { lastModified: true },
            },
            { upsert: true })
```

and after running this query my collection looks like.

[image]